# "is not a valid choice" when trying to update a field

Tags: django-rest-framework

I have this field in my User model

```
THEMES = [
    ("black", "black"),
    ("light", "light"),
    ("dark", "dark")
]

theme = models.CharField(
    max_length=100, choices=CHAT_STYLES,
    default=THEMES[1][1], null=True, blank=True
)
```

I'm trying to write a put request for it. this is the `serializer.py`

```
class UpdateThemeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ["theme"]

        def update(self, instance, validated_data):
            new_theme = validated_data["theme"]
            User.objects.update(theme=new_theme)
```

and here is the `view`

```
class UpdateTheme(APIView):
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]

    def put(self, request):
        serializer = UserSerializer(request.user, data=request.data, partial=True)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(data=serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors)
```

but when I test it in Postman i get this error

```
{
    "theme": [
        "\"dark\" is not a valid choice."
    ]
}
```

Comment: What is CHAT_STYLES? You use this value instead of THEMES in your model.

Answer (score 0):

Update this :

```
THEMES = [
    ("black", "black"),
    ("light", "light"),
    ("dark", "dark")
]

theme = models.CharField(
    max_length=100, choices=THEMES,
    default=THEMES[1][1], null=True, blank=True
)
```